# Movement caused by change of font size on css hover

Tags: html, css, hover

My menu:

```
<div id="menu_container">
    <ul>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div><!--//menu_container-->
```

My CSS:

```
#menu_container { text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1.3em; font-style: bold; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; float: left; height: 100%; }
#menu_container ul { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
#menu_container ul li { display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: #4e918b; }
#menu_container ul li:hover { font-weight: 900; }
```

My font is a Google font, hence the `font-weight` property.

When `hovering` a `li`, the other `li` are slightly moved. I know this question has been asked before, but I didn't find any solution working for my sample.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvxb1os1/18/) to make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the element widths are fluid, and determined by the width of the text, which increases when the font is bold. You could fix the problem by determining the computed widths of the individual elements and setting their widths to that. Something along the lines of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu_container ul li").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var width = $this.width();
    $this.css("width", width);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvxb1os1/20/

Alternatively, you could use a darker font color in place of bold text.

Comment: I'd rather use only CSS and no JS if possible. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the width of the containing elements or reduce the margin-left value as shown below.

```
 #menu_container ul li { 
     margin-left: 10px; 
   }
```

Below are some other solutions to the problem

1. reducing the font size
2. increasing the width of the containing element. Thereby being ready for the increase in font size and also stopping the movement. You can adjust the width until there are no movements.
3. removing or reducing the font weight.

[See this example fix.](http://jsfiddle.net/yvxb1os1/21/) Achieved by reducing margin-left, font-size and font-weight.

**Note:** It's only normal for the change in font size or font weight to cause a movement because you need  room to accommodate the increase in size of the text or else, it will move.

Comment: The movement is slighter but still there.

Comment: Adjust even further to suit you desire or eliminate the movement entirely.